# Log WCF Data Services POST contents

Tags: .net, wcf, iis, wcf-data-services

What is the best way to log the contents of anything POSTed to a WCF Data Service? I have tried using the service trace viewer but only see WebHeaders?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you configure the logging parameters correctly. You need to set the logEntireMessages attribute to true in the trace parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I had that set. In the contents of the service trace viewer I only see "</HttpRequest>... stream ...</MessageLogTraceRecord>" where I would expect to see the message contents.